# Run su -c "command" process

Tags: java, android

I want to use su to launch a command and read its output.
I tried this code:

```
        String line;
        Process cat=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"cat /etc/media_codecs.xml\"");
        BufferedReader catStream= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cat.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader catSerr= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cat.getErrorStream()));
        cat.waitFor();
        while((line=catSerr.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
         while((line=catStream.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

If I manually insert this command in the adb shell it works but with this code the phone asks me for root permission and If I accept I can read only this string to the stderr:

> tmp-mksh: cat /etc/media_codecs.xml: not found

And there is not stdout output. Why?

Comment: It's possible the file is not mounted for an application process, but more likely - and hinted by the error message - that the file is being interpreted as part of the name of the cat program, rather than as an argument to it.  Note there is no standard for the behavior of an 'su' program - any that actually work for this purpose are 3rd party hacks.

Comment: thanks. and what can I do to workaroud this problem?